# Publishing KoBoToolbox apk to playstore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-sheets-api, odk

I am new to kobotoolBox, I was required to add some changes to kobotoolBox project. I have successfully run the project in android studio and have applied changes and now need to publish that. 
I want to ask that I have cloned this project from  GitHub  means it has the same package name with which already an APK is published on play-store. What should I do to publish APK that I have created. Should I need to change the package name or there is another alternative way aside from changing package name??

Answer (score 0):

You may check [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html) to help you started.

> Publishing is the general process that makes your Android applications
>   available to users. When you publish an Android application you
>   perform two main tasks:
>
> 1. You prepare the application for release.
>
>    During the preparation step you build a release version of your
>      application, which users can download and install on their
>      Android-powered devices.
> 2. You release the application to users.
>
>    During the release step you publicize, sell, and distribute the
>      release version of your application to users.

Explore the page for you to get the proper steps when publishing an application.

Hope this helps.